# Best place for storing user login credentials in Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am creating an android app, and i cannot(?) find any information on authenticating a user of the app on Google App Engine (without using the user's Google Account).Is it good practice to store username and password on the android device and then store the data used by the app on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**You should NOT use `SharedPreferences`, despite how secure Google will tell you they are, for the simple fact that rooting habits are widespread by both power and wannabe-power users.**

In rooted systems, authorized apps will be able to access the **internal storage /system** partition, thus access the root-owned encrypted XML files where Android stores SharedPreferences, **WHICH BECOME CLEARTEXT FOR ROOT-AUTHORIZED APPS**. So if a compromised phone happens to have an app that stores such data and the user has a habit of abusing same email/password for different services, the attack vector is pretty straightforward to compromise credentials for multiple services, despite whatever warnings the user dismissed when rooting his phone or giving the app such permissions, because, well, those **warnings just aren't clear enough**.

Alternatives are manual encryption of persistent storage for credentials, using custom, variable seed, salted algorithms. [secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences) lib is a great alternative which pretty much does everything for you in a transparent way, with the added benefit of implementing Android's SharedPreferences interface, keeping most functionality of default sprefs with minor tweaking (look at their samples).

**2016 Edit:** I just felt I needed to come back to this question in 2016 and add a nice reference to the **Apple vs FBI drama** to alter the OS in the San Bernardino assailant's phone. So, imagine you have a phone that is easily rootable, like most Android's, and that might even be rooted by default or doesn't need to wipe data to root. The FBI doesn't have to demand anything from Google or your company if they wan't to get your credentials. By using stuff like **secure-preferences**, you place the same type of responsibility Apple decided to undertake by only making your own system (in this case, your app) able to access those credentials. You do get to be annoyed by the FBI if they so desire, but giving your users the sense that you, not the underlying OS, is the only authority having direct control over those credentials, is something I'd rather have in my product.

**2022 Edit**: Android has [Encrypted Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) natively now, so make use of that instead I would say (unless someone points out something it doesn't do better than secure-preferences)

Comment: I would say `SharedPreferences` is a good place to start from. Encrypting them is a must **if the app is going to be published**.

Comment: When dealing with passwords, the best place to start from is the least failure-prone place one knows. Android does not provide out of the box SharedPreferences encryption, nor the option to encrypt them. So I say the best place to start can't be a place that might end up in the final version for some reason. I had a similar issue and ended up using SecurePreferences https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences

Comment: OK, in my case I'm developing an internal enterprise application to be installed in a couple of tablets we've got here. As I've got a requirement to store the credentials, I consider more proper to start with a basic implementation of it. Encrypting them will be in the roadmap for next versions. Nobody here is gonna take the devices and root them to see others passwords :-)

Comment: My scenario was exactly the same as yours (internal app, but for smartphones) and managers noticed. They decided to do exactly what you expect managers not to do: rooted it and went straight to the XML. They filed a high priority bug, added no password saving feature, and I had to encrypt preferences THEN add a feature that makes no sense at all in the UX (asking password every single update) because they felt danger in the ecosystem. I ended up with triple the workload and a cluttered UX. I sh*t you not

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: you need to manage expectations about security very tightly from conception to development, or else you're gonna have a lot of overhead and bad design out of old policies that people still believe make things safer.

Comment: Actually what you are saying it is not 100% true as being a root you are like a "god" on a device so you can impostor application id and ask Keystore to decrypt the data even if encrypted. So again even if you encrypt on your own FBI could potentially access your data without asking Google to help in most cases. There is a nice comparison of available flows https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201068/android-what-are-the-practical-security-benefits-of-using-a-hardware-backed-ke

Answer (score -2):

You can save the user credentials in shared preference. You can use this preference value at any of your activity. The saved value will remains even after the exit from application. 
The sample code for shared preferences are here. It is recommended to keep your preferences code in your application utils class to keep your code organized.

```
  public static String KEY = "SESSION"; 
    public static void saveUserName(String userid, Context context) {
        Editor editor = context
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("username", userid);
        editor.commit();
    }

public static String getUserName(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return savedSession.getString("username", "");
}
```

Comment: @FranklySpeaking : I am telling you that how can you store the data locally in preference. You can also save your credentials to google app engine from preference. Check this out https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/

Answer (score -4):

Consider [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this, like...

```
public class PrefUtils {
    public static final String PREFS_LOGIN_USERNAME_KEY = "__USERNAME__" ;
    public static final String PREFS_LOGIN_PASSWORD_KEY = "__PASSWORD__" ;

    /**
     * Called to save supplied value in shared preferences against given key.
     * @param context Context of caller activity
     * @param key Key of value to save against
     * @param value Value to save
     */
    public static void saveToPrefs(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key,value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Called to retrieve required value from shared preferences, identified by given key.
     * Default value will be returned of no value found or error occurred.
     * @param context Context of caller activity
     * @param key Key to find value against
     * @param defaultValue Value to return if no data found against given key
     * @return Return the value found against given key, default if not found or any error occurs
     */
    public static String getFromPrefs(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        try {
            return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply use these methods like,

```
// Saving user credentials on successful login case
PrefUtils.saveToPrefs(YourActivity.this, PREFS_LOGIN_USERNAME_KEY, username);
PrefUtils.saveToPrefs(YourActivity.this, PREFS_LOGIN_PASSWORD_KEY, password);

// To retrieve values back
String loggedInUserName = PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(YourActivity.this, PREFS_LOGIN_USERNAME_KEY);
String loggedInUserPassword = PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(YourActivity.this, PREFS_LOGIN_PASSWORD_KEY);
```

I think its much clearer now...:)

Comment: Am sorry, but what am i supposed to do with this? could you explain?

Comment: Okay,so where do i use these methods again?

Comment: Hmmm...good question, Just make a separate class like Utility.java and place these methods in them by keeping these methods as **public static**, and use where ever you want...:)

Comment: I just read now that with SharedPreferences, user data gets deleted if the app is deleted? I think that's a problem.

Comment: yup...and even if user delete or clear app's memory form settings. Its actually temporary memory. But i think its fine for you...imagine, why would some need to have its user credentials after deleting the app...???

Comment: Good point.but what happens if the user wants to reinstall,or use the app on another device,what happens to his/her account?

Comment: Definetly you will need to implement you own machenism to transfer or store user credentials so that can be retrieved any time...may be one year later, or on any other device. I don't think such thing is available in android or even in any ther platform. You need to be more clear what you want actually...for now, it doesn't make sence to store user credential for such a long period...

Comment: By user credentials, i mean the username and password created when signing-up to my app.I can't find a way to create this account on GAE without using Google Account which is a restrictive option.So what i want is to create a user using my apps sign-up function, then connect  to GAE after the user signs in.

Comment: Do not store a password in shared preferences. If the user ever loses the phone, they've lost the password. It will be read. If they used that password elsewhere, everyplace they used it is compromised. In addition, you've permanently lost this account because with the password they can change your password. The correct way to do this is to send the password up to the server once, and receive a login token back. Store that in shared preference and send it up with each request. If that token is compromised, nothing else is lost.

Comment: @GabeSechan after I answered this question I never read this distributed alternative (a server is always the best place to store creds and authenticate). Still, I'd like to point out that losing the phone does not ensure password readability to the phone holder: if the phone was OEM locked (something essential for root in most cases), sharedprefs are encrypted and a bootloader unlock will trigger a full wipe, deleting sharedprefs (unlike if it was pre-rooted allowing). For fully offline auth, my answer still stands as safest, especially with SHA2 or ECDSA since SHA1 is compromised